# Accept pre-populated form field input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker, submit

I just set up my `date-picker` to auto populate it's input field with today's date.
Normally, a user would have to select their own date and `submit` their selection via the `enter` key or, I think in my case, any key would do it.

Is there anyway to automatically do this? Since the field is pre-populated, I want the results for today's date to appear automatically on page load, without the user needing to accept the date(today) that has been pre-populated into the field.

Here's my code if it's helpful:

```
<script>
function displayResult() {
    var k;
    if (window.event) // IE8 and earlier
    {
        k = event.keyCode;
    } else if (event.which) // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
    {
        k = event.which;
    }
    if (k == 13) //13 = 'Enter' key
    {
        var dt = $("#datepicker").val();
        //alert(dt);
        if (dt != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_date.php",
                data: "dt=" + dt,
                success: function (option) {
                    $("#results").html(option).listview("refresh");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#results").html("");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        changeMonth: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            //alert($('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate" ))
            //alert("dateText: " + dateText + ", inst: " + inst);
            var dt = dateText;

            if (dt != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search_date.php",
                    data: "dt=" + dt,
                    success: function (option) {
                        $("#results").html(option).listview("refresh");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#results").html("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
$('body').ready(function(){
var dt = $("#datepicker").val();
//alert(dt);
if(dt != '')
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search_date.php",
        data: "dt="+ dt,
        success: function(option)
        {
          $("#results").html(option).listview("refresh");
        }
  });
 }
 else
 {
   $("#results").html("");
 }
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: In order for this to work every time the user changes the value, you'll have to bind it to a change event. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').ready(function(){
    var dt = $("#datepicker").val();
    //alert(dt);
    if(dt != '')
     {
      $.ajax
      ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search_date.php",
            data: "dt="+ dt,
            success: function(option)
            {
              $("#results").html(option).listview("refresh");
            }
      });
     }
     else
     {
       $("#results").html("");
     }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked, however, now my datepicker is broken. My calendar no longer appears. Also, I am able to select the text field where the date shows, this allows me to choose a new date (via pop-up calendar), but only once. If I try to do this again nothing happens... no calendar appears to select a new date.

I'll update code above to reflect changes made